# Train and Test of a Boltzmann Machine

Tags: algorithm, matlab, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I managed to train a Boltzmann machine with 120 vissible units (size of pattern) and 60 hidden units (fully - connected) using bipolar pattern vectors. Reading Hinton notes i managed to follow the steps for training such a network in Matlab. In the possitive phase i clamped each pattern to the vissible units and let free the hidden units to update themselves in random configuration each time. Choosing each unit to update through Gibbs sampling - randomly and updating them stochastically through sigmoid function with a parameter of a reducing temperature (T) which is inspired from simulated annealing algorithm. If i let this process iterate many times i am able to collect the probability distribution over the training patterns, measuring P(h|v) first and calculating P(v) later. These probability terms are propotion to the energies that each time (at thermal equilibrium) the network settled. At the end of that i am collecting the statistics of the "wake up" phase as it called, keeping the **fixed states** (the thermal equilibrium configuration of the units at each pattern).I dont know why Hinton say P(v,h) here, i think it is P(h|v) because the vissible units are clamped and the hiddens are free to update with respect to the vissible units that are fixed.

Next, i am doing the same steps for the "dream" phase of the network initialize it with random configuration in all of the units and letting settle down to low energies, randomly updating all units stochastically. In this phase i am measuring the probability p(v,h) of all possible configrations. Once more i collect the **free states** (the thermal equilibrium configuration of the units at each pattern).

At the end i compare through Kullback distance the distributions (over patterns and over the model) and later on i update the weights subtracting the fixed states and free states which represents the corelation of the configurations at each phase. It turns out that partial derivative maximizing the pattern probabilities with respect to the weights is that difference that i said.

My original data are the following :

[image]

Maximizing the distribution over the vissible patterns and trying to "create" the same distribution in "dream phase" i end up with these ditributions. As you can see all of the patterns has the same probability in the distribution over patterns and in the internal distribution of the model.

[image]

Kullback distance, wich is a measurement of the difference of distributions end up in the value of 0.0000014049 which is very good. At last the weights of the hidden units respect to all the vissible units, are resized and end up to these realizations :

[image]

As you can see some of the weights of hidden layer learned all of the patterns and some others learned different pattern. So if all of the above are correct, in which way i can test the boltzmann machine. For example in a deterministic hopfield net after initialization of the weights through hebbian rule, i just input a noise pattern (corrupted) and let the network settle to the lowest energy it can get representing the original patterns (if we where lucky enough and not trapped in local minimum). So what is the test process in BM? I supose that the network must reconstruct each pattern with equal probability if i let it run freely once more with no external input, but this is not happening ..